# This question did not getting much response after the major edit, and received a close vote without any reason being mentioned.

Tags: discussion

This is a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504426/2987) posted by me a few days ago. I after initial comments made by users, I have done a major edit. After this major edit, I couldn't get a single comment or response for this question. Moreover someone has voted to close, without mentioning any reason for it. I'd appreciate if that user gives a reason. I'd like to know what are the problems with this question?

**EDIT :** Even the bounty has expired and still no activity. It has been already 2 weeks. Wonder if its a good idea to migrate it to MO and see.

Comment: @robjohn and other moderators, may be you can close this question.

Comment: Bounties have a "grace period" of 24 hours, where the bounty is actually still somewhat active.  For the question you are concerned with, this ends in about 9 hours.  Until this expires it is still not possible to simply migrate the question.  I have kept your flag open (and likely the other moderators as well), and when this period ends someone will undoubtedly migrate it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A few notes:

1. A single close vote is not something to get too worked up over.  (Especially seeing as your  question has no downvotes compared to four upvotes at this time.)
2. While it may seem impolite, users are not required to disclose their reason for voting to close in a comment.  *If* the question is closed, then a reason will be disclosed.
3. Bringing extra attention to your questions — and inquiring as to why your question has received close votes — may easily be viewed as a mis-use of meta.math.SE.  (This is likely why *this* question is receiving downvotes.)
4. It seems like at least one user had some interest in your question before your edits, and he may be unaware of your latest edits.  You could try `@`-pinging him in a comment to request additional comments.  (There is no guarantee of a response, of course.)

Comment: Thanks @Arthur Fischer

Answer (score 8):

You should try bounties instead. That brings more attention and more efficiently as well.

Comment: The featured section already has more than 50 questions currently. So most probably it may not get any more attention.